# How to Change Route File Location In Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, router

I will try to change my route file location but its ganerate error so i'm reset all my project code when its compalet reset but after its genrate this error. so how to fix this error.

[image]

> RouteServicveProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as 
ServiceProvider;
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
   /**
   * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
   *
   * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
   *
   * @var string
   */
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
   parent::boot();
}
/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();
    $this->mapWebRoutes();
}
/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}}
```

> C:\wamp64\www\example\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in file `C:\wamp64\www\example\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php` line 3. And also remove 'F' before

Comment: Thanks .!! Sorry its my mistake

Answer (score 0):

To change the location of the routes file, you can do the following in your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->loadRoutes();
}

/**
 * Register the application routes.
 */
public function loadRoutes(): void
{
    Route::group([
        'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'
    ], function () {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/path/to/routes.php');
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry.!! i can't Understand. please again explain me.

Answer (score 0):

There is just `F` typing so the error is genrat.

[image]